Continuity of a root of a sequence of polynomials when extending one of the exponents of the polynomial sequence to be real
Consider the polynomial
$$
x^n+a x+b
$$
Suppose that I showed that for some regime of $a$ and $b$, the polynomials $x^n+a x+b$ have a unique positive root (the polynomial sequence provided is just an example, I did not check if this is possible with that polynomial sequence). I can define a sequence $s[n]$  to be the unique positive root of those polynomials.
Question

Are there conditions where I could take $n$ to be real and affirm that
$s[n]$ is a continuous function and is the unique positive root for
all positive real valued $n$ of the function $f[n,x,a,b]=x^n+a x+b$ ?

I am concerned whether some new positive roots could appear for values of $n$ between its integer part and the integer that follows and that roots could be swapped at a non integer value of $n$.

Do you know the “implicit function theorem”?

@MartinR Yes (I remember it after checking Wikipedia for the detailed statement) but I think that would only ensure that it makes sense to generalize to non integer values of $n$. It would not ensure that across two consecutive integer values of $n$, a new root is not formed and that as $n$ increased it took the place of a root that was defined at a previous value of $n$ and it just looks like it was the same root at $n$ and $n+1$ but it was switched if we look at the whole animation instead of just snapshots.
